# Store new array inside for loop in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, iphone, xcode

So I have this for statement looping inside movies and Im able to print the results for
the keys "title and "type".
I want to display those results in a ViewController or table cell.
My question is how can I create new array and append it to the Dictionary results data and accessing it outside the for loop .

```
   if let movies = json["ITEMS"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>> {
                
              
                for movie in movies {
                   
                    
                    
                   print(movie["title"] ?? "")
                   print(movie["type"] ?? "")
                
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: Make a variable of viewController to save movies, and now you can do every thing you want

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. Im new to swift you mind showing me an example code of this thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable in your view controller, and a struct or a class for your model.

**Here is how:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    
    struct Movie {
        var title: String
        var type: String
    }

    var globalMovies = [Movie]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseMovies() 
    }

    func parseMovies() { 
        if let movies = json["ITEMS"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>> {
        for movie in movies {    
                print(movie["title"] ?? "")
                print(movie["type"] ?? "")
                globalMovies.append(Movie(title: movie["title"] ?? "", type: movie["type"] ?? ""))
            }
        }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your help . I tried your example but it seems like the append or the values from the for loop are not being saved in the new globalMovies array and can be only access via the original array (Movies) I don't understand way they made it so complicated its should be an easy thing to achieve in any programing language